# What will the next ISS resupply launch be named?

Tags: launch, spacex, failure

Commercial Resupply Services (CRS) are contracts awarded by NASA for delivery of cargo and supplies to the International Space Station (ISS) on commercially operated spacecraft. SpaceX signed a contract for 15 launches, the first of which was named **CRS-1**, and launched on 7th October, 2012.

Subsequent launches were named using step-iteration. However on June 28, 2015, **CRS-7** experienced a [launch failure](http://spaceref.biz/company/spacex-falcon-9-mishap-more-details-emerge.html), resulting in a 'loss-of-vehicle'.

**Presuming SpaceX gets FAA clearance to re-fly the mission, what will the launch be called? What is the protocol followed for naming launches in the events of A) *failure with loss-of-vehicle* or B) *failure with an undamaged vehicle*.**

**In the event that the launch is transferred to another corporation (eg. Orbital Sciences), are the old naming conventions retained?**

Comment: Since Elon himself, or some students he hired, seem to come up with the crazy names thus far, I'd propose: "Of course I'll come back to you, honey", "Sorry, I didn't mean to hit you that hard", "I hope you will stand up for me this time", "Burn burn burn". Pick your favourite ;-)

Comment: Considering the CRS-6 landing, *'I hope you will stand up for me this time'* is my pick!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The next Orbital Cygnus flight, on Atlas V is called Orb-4 (per SpaceflightNow.com's launch schedule).

Since the lost flight was Orb-3, then we can assume that SpaceX will follow a similar pattern and the next flight will be CRS-8.

The next Progress is named 60, after Progress 59 failed. So looks like the pattern (2 data points makes a line, one data point tells you everything when on the Internet) is to just increment the count and move on.

Comment: +∞ for "*one data point tells you everything when on the Internet*"

Answer (score 4):

Mission names are never reused.  Even if the mission never launches or fails to reach orbit, reusing the name would cause confusion in documenting separate missions.

Comment: How about adding an 'A' to the name.  How about Soyuz 18 and 18a? Ok, that is the only example I could find, so meh. Mostly disprove my own point.  Nuts to that!

Comment: @geoffc, in the Soviet Union, failed missions never existed, so there's no re-use of names.

Comment: @Mark Budda boom.  Good point. The non-people.